# Copy a large DB schema to create a new DB in EF Code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a code first DB with a context , from which i need to create a new DB which uses that Data but modifies it say 5% of the fields and then adds 20 more tables . This migration will be a regular daily process where many new Dbs are created ( from many source DBs) .

What is the best way to do this .. right now im using a rather horrible method which copies across one table after another ( using value mapper for fields) and then does a few parent patches ?  Its horrible because its slow but worse the order is dependent on relationships and Many to Many are a pain.  ( in addition i have to match up ids if the original table has an id missing)

I thought of using an SQL query but that is a bit difficult as well for such an operation ( especially since the destination uses different classnames for inheritance)  and may be an issue if some Dbs move to Oracle.

A brute copy which ignores foreign keys would be ideal.

Any ideas ? And remember this is a 50 table DB.

Comment: This does not seem like a task for EF.

Comment: how else do code first inheritance in sql ? ( db1 uses shared table , db2 uses table  per class)

Comment: EF (a single context) cannot work with more than one database at the same time. EF is not a good tool to do DBA kind of work across databases. EF is also not really suited for DB bulk operations (it will be slow). For changes to a single database schema you may use migrations. EF is great when working with adding and/or manipulating data in the database, track changes and relationships etc. but for me it seems that it will be hard to use it in your scenario.

Comment: So what to use this will be deployed to users who have a local SQLEXPRESS db .. no DBAs around..

Comment: Performance is not so much of an issue but integrity is ..eg that identity keys stay the same . SO if there is a deleted record on the old DB the new one skips it . ( I cant see anything actually coping all the FK relations correctly if it doesnt skip it)